# Unexpected results from CFQUERY and CFIF comparison

Tags: coldfusion, railo, lucee

This piece of code is in production to block IP's based on usage. An email was triggered, and an insert executed, with an IP address satisfying the cfif condition. However, when I executed the query in the SQL editor, for the same IP, it returned the count as 0 (ie getNineHundredCnt.maxDownload).

This happened for only one user. It is working fine for rest of the users, with almost 1L users accessing the application daily. Can anyone help explain why it happened?

```
<cfquery name="getExcessiveUsageConfig" DATASOURCE="#arguments.datasrc#">
    SELECT * FROM ExcessiveUsageConfig
</cfquery>

<cfset usageLimitStruct.maxFifMinDownload = getExcessiveUsageConfig.MAXFIFMINDOWNLOAD >

<!---- This value is 900 and not changed --->
<cfquery name="getNineHundredCnt" DATASOURCE="#arguments.datasrc#">
   SELECT 
         ( select count(9)  
           from   downloads 
           where  download_time > dateadd(minute,-15,getdate()) 
           and    USER_IP = <cfqueryparam value="#remoteAddress#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">
        ) as maxDownload,
        ( select TOP 1 DATEDIFF(second, DOWNLOAD_TIME, GETDATE())  
          from   CAPTCHA 
          WHERE  USER_IP = <cfqueryparam value="#remoteAddress#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR"> 
          and    Erights_sessionId = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.erightsCookie#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">
          order by DOWNLOAD_TIME DESC
        ) as Ccheck 
</cfquery>


<cfif getNineHundredCnt.maxDownload gte usageLimitStruct.maxFifMinDownload>

   <cfquery name="checkToBlockIpExcessUsage" DATASOURCE="#arguments.dataAuthentication#">
      INSERT INTO DisabledIPs(IP,TIMEDISABLED)
      VALUES (<cfqueryparam value="#remoteAddress#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">,GETDATE())
   </cfquery>

     <cfmail from="xxx@xxx.com" to="xxx@xxx.com" subject="IP Blocked"  type="text">
     IP : #remoteAddress#
     Time : #currentTime#
     The IP has been blacklisted 
     </cfmail>

</cfif>
```

Comment: is there a chance of returning 0 as values from sql query if the query timedout?

Comment: How many rows are in ExcessiveUsageConfig?

Comment: its only one row, and the value of column MAXFIFMINDOWNLOAD  is 900

Comment: Add the variables to the email, so you can trace them if it happens again. *when I executed the query in sql editor* For the same time period? The results could be different if executed later. (BTW, The question is tagged with three engines. Specifically, which one are you using?)

Comment: What happens when you run the `getNineHundredCnt` query using ColdFusion, outside this function?

Comment: @Leigh its coldfusion 8 and MS sql  2008 R2, and there are no records at all for the ip  in "downloads" table, so not to worry about the time.

Comment: @DanBracuk maxDownload: 0, Ccheck : Null

Comment: one more thing what I observed is that a timegap of 30 minutes between time in Cfmail (Time : #currentTime#) &  TIMEDISABLED column in  DisabledIPs table. both were happened at the same request

Comment: I got the same thing happened today and made some analysis on Fusion Reactor, As soon as I received the email. The cause is ip in the query is different and ip in the email & DisabledIPs is different, What would be the cause?

Comment: @nikhilreddy - Is it possible this code is contained in a cffunction and you forgot to `var/local` scope all of the variables? If so, it could lead to race conditions and the scenario you described. The solution is to `var/local` scope *all* of the function local variables, including query names.

Comment: yes @Leigh, im not using the scope inside the function, Also, im using GetHttpRequestData().headers["X-Forwarded-For"]) for client ip address instead from CGI variables, Will that lead to race condition?

Comment: @nikhilreddy - If the function/cfc is accessed by multiple threads, then yes it could experience race conditions. You need to localize all of the function local variables - including query names.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is that getNineHundredCnt.maxDownload is 0 and usageLimitStruct.maxFifMinDownload is 0 as well. Output the values and verify.